# r.net RDotNet.REngine does not contain a definition for 'GetInstance'

Tags: r.net

I copied the code right from the documentation http://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet/tut_basic_types/

REngine.SetEnvironmentVariable() and REngine.GetInstance() both give compiler errors saying 'RDotNet.REngine' does not contain a definition.

I installed nuget package R.Net Version 1.5.5 and I am running a c# console application.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using RDotNet;

namespace Sample1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(); // <-- May be omitted; the next line would call it.
            REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
            // A somewhat contrived but customary Hello World:
            CharacterVector charVec = engine.CreateCharacterVector(new[] { "Hello, R world!, .NET speaking" });
            engine.SetSymbol("greetings", charVec);
            engine.Evaluate("str(greetings)"); // print out in the console
            string[] a = engine.Evaluate("'Hi there .NET, from the R engine'").AsCharacter().ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("R answered: '{0}'", a[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit the program");
            Console.ReadKey();
            engine.Dispose();

        }
    }
}
```

I googled and could not find an answer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two R.Net nugget packages from different publishers. I installed the wrong one. oops.

The right package for this example is [R.NET.Community](https://www.nuget.org/packages/R.NET.Community/).

Comment: please edit your answer! I was doing your same mistake, the right package for this example is R.NET.Community!

Comment: Is there any way you people found? Like if I dont install the package and use R.Net with the dlls only. I will get the dlls by installing and then uninstall it to use it direct from dlls.

Comment: You can use dlls just by selecting add reference and the file location of your dll